# I am sending you home

Tags: word-usage, grammar

He was after tuition. He was picking him up to home.

"Where are we going?" He asked.

> **"I am sending you home."**

I told him as I will go to work after that.

Can send use on person? We usually say send for things. How about person?

Comment: Side question, where or how is "tuition" used in this way any more?  I've never heard of it -- to me the more natural expressions are "tutoring", "tutelage", "instruction", "teaching", or "lessons".   "Tuition" only refers to the *cost* of such things.  I'm not saying it's *wrong*, but I am curious where it might still be common.

Comment: I think you mean **school** or **lessons**, but not "tuition".  We don't really use the word "tuition"  the way you're using it.  Also, you would have to say something like "He had gotten out of school" or "It was after his school", but you can't say "*He was* after school".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing inherently improper in speaking of *sending* a person somewhere.

In this case, however, it appears that you are not *sending* the student home. To *send* someone or something to a destination means to cause them to leave your presence and move to the destination; but if someone or something remains with you while you move to the destination you *take* them there.